# can't login to ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu-10.10

I installed ubuntu 10.10 on my eee pc 901 netbook and get authentication failure on login when I type in my username and password.

Comment: Is your CapsLock key on? Are you *sure* you're inputting the correct user/password?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you put the wrong password in both times when installing it. That seriously happened to me once, and the only way (as far as I know) to remedy this is to do a clean reinstall. Which, seeing as how this is a clean install, shouldn't be much of an issue.